# Null Pointer Exception When Switching window

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am having problem when trying to access .fxml from different package. Lets say my login.fxml is in customer package. After successfully logged in, it will go to home page. In the home page, I got a button tat link to myShoppingCart.fxml which is in cart package. However, I got null pointer exception error when I did this:

```
public void goToCart(ActionEvent event) {
    String userName = CustomerLoginController.userLoggedIn.getName();
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        Pane p = (Pane) fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("cartCustHome.fxml").openStream());
        CartCustHomeUI fooController = (CartCustHomeUI) fxmlLoader.getController();
        fooController.retrieveUserName(userName);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        Scene scene = new Scene(p);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(MainFrame.class.getResource("cart.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        ((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It's not getting my cartCustHome.fxml eventhough I've imported my cart package. I wonder why is it so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is relationship between myShoppingCart.fxml and cartCustHome.fxml? At which line the exception occurs? Search the net as "java getresource returns null".

Comment: both of them in different packages

Comment: Your button links to myShoppingCart.fxml but iin its action tries to load cartCustHome.fxml? Anyway try `getClass().getResource("../customer/cartCustHome.fxml").openStream()`.

Comment: @UlukBiy Sorry for my naming convention. The cartCustHome supposed to be cart home page. And yeah, it works, can you make it as an answer so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
getClass().getResource("../customer/cartCustHome.fxml").openStream()
```

For more info please search the site for "java getresource returns null". There are lots of discussion on this topic and they provide comprehensive explanations.

Comment: But I think it works with getClass().getResource("/customer/cartCustHome.fxml").openStream(); Thanks a lot